# Displaying R plots in a 1x4 grid, using a shared y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display some graphs in a 1x4 grid, but I would like all the graphs to have the same x and y axes.

```
time maxhgs.sleep_LIPA maxhgs.sed_LIPA maxhgs.stand_LIPA maxhgs.MVPA_LIPA maxhgs.LIPA_MVPA
1    5        0.08289621      0.03241295         0.1129983      0.112998341      -0.01928050
2   10        0.16289049      0.06139545         0.2236818     -0.006728721      -0.04950022
3   15        0.24025861      0.08721203         0.3323473     -0.047756360      -0.08927656
4   20        0.31524160      0.11009218         0.4392581     -0.144261526      -0.13791276
5   25        0.38805152      0.13023596         0.5446498     -0.424789999      -0.19517306
6   30        0.41660977      0.13756729         0.5864293     -0.934884300      -0.26117695
```

This is the data I am working with.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

maxhgs.a <- ggplot(maxhgs.df, aes(time, maxhgs.sleep_LIPA)) + geom_point()+geom_line()
maxhgs.a <- maxhgs.a + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time Reallocated", breaks = seq(5,30, by=5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Change in maxhgs", breaks = seq(0,1, by=0.1))+
  ggtitle("Sleep to LIPA")

maxhgs.b <- ggplot(maxhgs.df, aes(time, maxhgs.sed_LIPA)) + geom_point()+geom_line()
maxhgs.b <- maxhgs.b + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time Reallocated", breaks = seq(5,30, by=5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Change in maxhgs", breaks = seq(0,1, by=0.1))+
  ggtitle("Sedentary to LIPA")

maxhgs.c <- ggplot(maxhgs.df, aes(time, maxhgs.stand_LIPA)) + geom_point()+geom_line()
maxhgs.c <- maxhgs.c + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time Reallocated", breaks = seq(5,30, by=5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Change in maxhgs", breaks = seq(0,1, by=0.1))+
  ggtitle("Standing to LIPA")

maxhgs.d <- ggplot(maxhgs.df, aes(time, maxhgs.MVPA_LIPA)) + geom_point()+geom_line()
maxhgs.d <- maxhgs.d + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time Reallocated", breaks = seq(5,30, by=5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Change in maxhgs", breaks = seq(0.5,-1, by=-0.1))+
  ggtitle("MVPA to LIPA")


ggarrange(maxhgs.a, 
          maxhgs.b + 
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ), 
          maxhgs.c + 
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ),
          maxhgs.d +
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ), 
          nrow = 1)
```

This is what I have attempted so far. This actually "works" in that all the graphs have the same y-axis, but the y-axis doesn't actually reflect what should be on the graphs. As you can see in the graph, the y-axis goes from 0.1 to 0.4, but the maxhgs.d graph should extend from 0.1 to -0.9.

[image]

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this much easier by reshaping your data and using faceting. That way, you only need to define a single plot. This requires you to `pivot_longer` and change the factor levels to the names you want for each facet, but once this is done, the plot itself is straightforward:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Define the label names for the facets first
labs <- c("LIPA to MVPA", "MVPA to LIPA", "Sedentary to LIPA",
          "Sleep to LIPA", "Standing to LIPA")

gg <- maxhgs.df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -1) %>% 
  mutate(plot = factor(`levels<-`(factor(name), labs), labs[c(4, 3, 5, 2, 1)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Time Reallocated") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Change in maxhgs") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 13))
```

Now we can either choose to plot with fixed y axes:

```
gg + facet_grid(.~plot, scale = "fixed")
```

[image]

or with flexible y axes:

```r
gg + facet_wrap(.~plot, scale = "free_y", ncol = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and is exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: If I wanted to add another graph of LIPA to MVPA what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Tim I would happily update my answer to show you. Can I point out that from an etiquette point of view that unaccepting an answer that was correct for the original question, then asking a secondary question in the comments is considered bad form. Most folks, myself included, are happy to respond to secondary questions without you having to do this, and on the contrary some may take offence.

Comment: Thank you. My apologies, I was not familiar with that aspect of etiquette here, and I certainly did not mean to offend anyone!

Comment: No need to apologize Tim. Please see my update - is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly! Thanks for all your help